# Making a radio-controlled clock work from a local time signal

Tags: arduino, rf, radio, time

Is it possible to modify radio-controlled clocks (so-called "atomic" clocks, like https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wall-Clocks-Radio-Controlled/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A376322011%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A1249834031) to synchronise to an arbitrary (local) time signal rather than the standard time signal (i.e. MSF in the UK, WWVB in US, or any number of other time signal stations across the world)?

As I see it, this would involve two parts:

a.) Adjusting the radio receiver in the unit to listen on a different radio frequency of a locally-provided time signal rather than the default frequency

b.) Broadcast the desired time signal in the expected format on that frequency.

I've had a look at the signal standard, and I think I'd be able to broadcast a signal as described here http://www.npl.co.uk/upload/pdf/MSF_Time_Date_Code.pdf using a handful of components and an Arduino.
However, I'm not really sure how I'd approach adjusting the receiver as described in a.) - or whether there's a better approach I could take? (or other flaws in my plan I haven't considered), and my Google-fu has not brought up any useful resources to suggest others having achieved this in the past. I wondered whether I'd even need to change the frequency, or whether producing a local signal on the same frequency would have sufficient power to "override" the official time signal?
Any advice would be gratefully received!

To further explain my purpose; I'm not trying to improve the accuracy - I'm trying to broadcast and display an arbitrary local "stopwatch" time, unrelated to whatever the actual current time might be. (From asker's asker's clarifying comment)

Comment: The main question is why bother?  You can't improve on the accuracy of the existing standard time signals. WWWB can be reliably received over most of the United States.  What advantages are there in your scheme.

Comment: 1) link to the product doesn't work 2) it depends on the product if it is "hackable", only the people who designed it can tell you for sure. Maybe it has a (mask) ROM so every setting is "burned" forever into the system. 3) It would be much easier to build your own radio controlled clock and make it receive what you want. 4) you might not be allowed to **transmit** timing signals even if it is for your own use!

Comment: @Barry - Sorry - I didn't explain my purpose; I'm not trying to improve the accuracy - I'm trying to broadcast and display an arbitrary local "stopwatch" time, unrelated to whatever the actual current time might be.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - 1.) Sorry, that got mangled. I don't have particular product in mind - but general type is any of https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wall-Clocks-Radio-Controlled/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A376322011%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A1249834031. 2.) Indeed. I guess I was looking for suggestions as to how I might be able to tell any given product was "hackable" before buying dozens of different units and tkaing them apart. 3.) I'm not sure it would - have tried that in the past and internal clock mechanics are very fiddly! 4.) If I did it in the 433MHz range, say, shouldn't need licence?

Comment: You ain't gonna "adjust" a typical radio clock to receive on 433MHz.  You will have to replace the receiver entirely.  The clock signals a typically broadcast on a low frequency.  Germany uses 77kHz - there is no way you are going to adjust a receiver for that to receive a 433MHz signal.

Comment: You'd probably have more luck removing the antenna and injecting a very weak signal at the original frequency, probably through a tiny series capacitor.  But be sure no part of your generator can radiate to interfere with others.

Comment: *If I did it in the 433MHz range, say, shouldn't need licence?* Indeed, 433 MHz is one of the "free" ISM bands, you can use it without a license. You might already use 433 MHz for your car key, garage door opener or weather station.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - that's actually a brilliant idea! I'm pretty sure I can create the correct transmission signal, so I can just inject that output direct in place of the clock antenna signal, which would do away with the need to adjust the receiver frequency at all. The only potential problem that leaves is as mentioned by glen_geek that the clock may only adjust periodically to the signal received, but that's something that may differ on a unit-by-unit basis. Thankyou - I'm off to experiment!

Comment: If you're talking about an analogue clock with a dial and hands, wouldn't it be simplest to leave the electronics alone and move the hour hand to any of the 12 hours of the clock face?  RC clocks in the U.S. usually feature only four time zone options, so they can't be used outside the contiguous 48 states and can't display times elsewhere in the world, such as UTC/GMT.  However, if I were to pry the hour hand loose, advance it a few hours and press it back onto the shaft, the clock should be able to accurately display time for any city on Earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commercial products are very difficult to adapt for other purposes:

- Data rates are very slow, often one bit-per-second.
- Clocks often only "update" periodically, (once an hour? a few times per day?)
- Frequency of operation is very precise, perhaps crystal-controlled.
- Highly integrated for low cost.

Am mostly familiar with WWVB, and *have* programmed a microcontroller to receive its 60 kHz signal. The project is not recommended for novices.

Data transmission via radio over short distances is a common desire served by RF modules...the transmitter accepts digital input, and the receiver outputs a digital replica. Ensure that the operating frequency and power are appropriate for your region.

Comment: Point 2 is what makes this completely impossible, rather than very difficult

Comment: I'm not so sure about point 2 though. It is my understanding that they update essentially every time they receive a complete frame with correct checksums, which happens _at most_ once every minute.

Comment: @pipe Some turn off the radio receiver during the day when noise & propagation is poor to save battery power.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comments. Indeed, point 2 would be a killer I hadn't considered. From the spec sheet I linked to "The  first second  of  the  minute  begins  with  a  period  of  500  ms  with  the  carrier  off,  to  serve  as  a  minute  marker.  The  other 59 (or, exceptionally, 60 or 58) seconds of the minute always begin with at least 100 ms 'off' and end with at least 700  ms  of  carrier. " gave me the impression that the signal was broadcast every second, and therefore a clock could be made to sync to it at that frequency too?

Comment: @AlastairAitchison Available are **receiver-only** modules, with ferrite antenna that would seem suitable for your purposes (product promotions are forbidden here). You'd require a microcontroller to decode the pulse widths, and to drive a mechanical clock mechanism. These receivers provide pulse output as long as you apply DC power.

Answer (score 2):

You could transmit on the standard frequency, or hack the clock to receive another.

How far do you want to transmit to this clock?

If only an inch or so, then you may be able transmit at such low power that you can drown out the national signal at the clock, and be so low power that you don't upset the neighbours, or the FCC. Any antenna would be near field at those frequencies, and so a well aligned nearly direct coupling to the clock's ferrite rod would end up broadcasting practically no EM radiation.

If you are trying to transmit metres, then that would be illegal in any jurisdiction. You would need to use a power that will upset your neighbours' timekeeping, and would bring down the wrath of the telecommunication authorities.

As for hacking a clock, it's a case of open one and see. Older clocks might be better, more likely to have a separate RF section with audio modulation out. If I was designing one these days, I might be inclined to do something clever with subsampling the RF directly after a bit of tuned amplification, and so bury the demodulator in silicon. If you can locate the modulation, then it should be a cinch to drive with the output of your 433MHz garage door opener. Test it with your Arduino directly first though.

Do you want the clock to actually *be* a radio wall clock, or look like one, or just look like a clock? With a display and an Arduino, you could write a clock, and equip it with your garage door opener receiver, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I don't want it to actually *be* a clock that tells the time - I want a clock that can be controlled to display an arbitrary value that can be encoded as HH:MM. To be clear, I'm talking about an "analogue" clock here with hour and minute hands. If I was creating a digital clock display, I'd obviously just wire a 7-segment display block to the Arduino and be done with it :) I *thought* that it would be easier to modify the electronics of an existing radio-controlled clock unit rather than fiddle around with tiny cogs required to make my own mechanism, but maybe not!

Comment: Yes, sub-sampling 60 kHz analog input (into microcontroller AD) after a bit of gain & selectivity is possible. Pushes a simple 8-bit microcontroller to its limit - it is not an easy project. A 433 MHz pulse-coded (OOK) radio link is far more straightforward. In any case, OP *still* has to drive a mechanical display mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

> To be clear, I'm talking about an "analogue" clock here with hour and minute hands. If I was creating a digital clock display, I'd obviously just wire a 7-segment display block to the Arduino and be done with it :) I thought that it would be easier to modify the electronics of an existing radio-controlled clock unit rather than fiddle around with tiny cogs required to make my own mechanism

With this clarification of goal, it's worth pointing out that most "analog" clocks of an electrical nature actually employ a small single-coil unidirectional variety of stepper motor to drive the gear train.  The coil is pulsed at an appropriate interval divided from a quartz crystal (or perhaps in line powered models the mains frequency).  This tends to be true everywhere from AA-battery pound shop models up through models you might find in a school which take a wired signal from a master clock.

Because of their digital stepper-motor nature, it's quite possible to drive the electromechanical mechanism from your own pulse circuit rather than the original.   Many people have used this to create their own versions of the infamous "Lord Ventinari's Clock" from Terry Prachett's Discworld novels.  In that application, the clock is pulsed at an erratic rate intended to discomfort viewers, but the number of pulses is tracked and controlled so that the average time advanced is correct over longer periods.

Such a mechanism would of course have a maximum step rate, but if that is determined and honored and by careful counting of sent pulses, you should be able to walk the hands to arbitrary positions through the use of just about any small MCU.   This will be far simpler than trying to produce a false time reference signal to similarly walk a radio-referenced clock's hands *through* its existing electronics.  It's perhaps possible that in order to support self-setting radio-referenced models may have mechanisms supporting higher step rates than ordinary ones, but even in that case, it's going to be easier to *replace* the drive electronics and take advantage of the more capable mechanism, than to try to drive the mechanism by misleading the electronics with a false reference signal.